# trying to print a pdf file but got an error , my code is correctly working with image print and txt file print but when i print pdf file its error

Tags: pdf, error-handling, printing

import os

try:

```
    file = "C:\\Cheque_Software\\All_Data\\ISSUE_CHEQUE.pdf"
    os.startfile(file, "print")
```

except Exception as Ex:

```
    print(f"ERROR DUE TO : {str(Ex).title()}")
```

else:

```
    print("your printer is not connected with system".title())
```

ERROR IS

ERROR DUE TO : [Winerror 1155] No Application Is Associated With The Specified File For This Operation: 'C:\Cheque_Software\All_Data\Issue_Cheque.Pdf'emphasized text

Comment: Seems like the OS is telling you there is no application defined to print PDF files. You need to install an application which knows how to open PDF files and print them. Acrobat Reader for example.

Comment: @KenS I am beginner, Can you show code please bro?

Comment: Well no, not really. You need to install an application which can print PDF files, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: first open pdf file with python in Acrobat Reader ? or i need to install Acrobat Reader in my system C location?